# Running a zsh script from a python script

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, sh, zsh

I have a shell function that I would like to test from within a python script. It contains the double bracket `[[` syntax which can only be interpreted by bash/zsh/ksh etc., but not the regular shell. In the original file, I read the function from a sh file using the `builtins.open` function. I simplified this case a bit and already added the file to the script as a string exactly the way it is loaded in the original file. I then paste it into subprocess with the shell argument set to True:

```
shell_function = """example_shell_function () {
  #calling a python script which prints values to stdout
  output_string=$(python3 test.py);
  output_snippet=$(echo $output_string | tail -n1)
  test_sign="@"
  #if output_snippet contains "@" then enter condition
  if [[ "$output_snippet" =~ "$test_sign" ]]
  then
    echo "condition met"
  else
    echo "condition not met"
  fi
}"""
shell_commands = "\n".join(shell_function+["example_shell_function"])
    process = subprocess.Popen(shell_commands_test_argument,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
             stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

I am running zsh on my machine, but subprocess uses the regular `sh` binary and returns the error `[[: not found` on the line where the double brackets are defined in the script. I have tried modifying the subprocess call as following, in order to make sure the function is interpreted by zsh instead of sh:

```
shell_commands = "\n".join([". /bin/zsh"]+shell_function+["example_shell_function"])
```

This returns the error `/bin/sh: 2: /bin/zsh: : not found`, in spite of the zsh binary being present at that location. What is the best way to run this function from within my python script?

Comment: Use `executable='/usr/bin/zsh'` in your `subprocess()` call.

Comment: Another option is to replace the `[[ ]]` with `test`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution proposed by @MarkSetchell worked:

> Use executable='/usr/bin/zsh' in your subprocess() call.